# Почему этот компонент (home.js) вызывается дважды, несмотря на то, что я написал React.memo

Tags: javascript, reactjs

// ACTION

```
import axios from "axios";
import {API} from "../../constants";
import * as type from "../types";

function error() {
    return new Error("Error from server");
}

// GET List all posts

export const get_listAllPosts = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(API._get)
            .then(res => res.data);
        dispatch(dispatchListAllPosts(res));
    } catch (e) {
        error()
    }
};

export const dispatchListAllPosts = (posts) => ({
    type: type.GET_POSTS,
    posts
});
```

// REDUCER

```
import * as type from "../types";

const initialState = {
    posts: []
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case type.GET_POSTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                posts: action.posts
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

// COMPONENT

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import blogImage from "../images/blog.jpg";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {del_deletePost, get_listAllPosts} from "../redux/actions/postAction";
import {getData, getLoading} from "../redux/selectors";

const Home = React.memo(({posts, get_listAllPosts, del_deletePost, history}) => {

    console.log("render"); // вызывается дважды

    useEffect(() => {
        get_listAllPosts()
    }, [get_listAllPosts]);

    function handleDeletePost(id) {
        const remove = window.confirm("Are you sure delete the post: " + id);
        if (remove) {
            del_deletePost(id)
        }
    }

    return (
        <main role="main">
            <section className="jumbotron text-center mb-0">
                <div className="container">
                    <h1>Blog</h1>
                </div>
            </section>

            <div className="album py-5 bg-light">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        {
                            posts && posts.map(post => {
                                return (
                                    <div className="col-md-4" key={post.id}>
                                        <div className="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
                                            <img src={blogImage} alt="" style={{width: "100%", height: "250px"}}/>
                                            <div className="card-body">
                                                <h5 className="card-title">{post.title}</h5>
                                                <p className="card-text">{post.body}</p>
                                                <div className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                                    <div className="btn-group">
                                                        <button
                                                            type="button"
                                                            className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success"
                                                            onClick={() => history.push(`/post/${post.id}`)}
                                                        >View
                                                        </button>
                                                        <button
                                                            type="button"
                                                            className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary"
                                                            onClick={() => history.push(`/edit/${post.id}`)}
                                                        >
                                                            Edit
                                                        </button>
                                                        <button
                                                            type="button"
                                                            className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger"
                                                            onClick={() => handleDeletePost(post.id)}
                                                        >
                                                            Delete
                                                        </button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </main>
    );
});

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        posts: getData(state)
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {get_listAllPosts, del_deletePost})(Home);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Memo` это не значит что твой компонент никогда не будет рендерится.

В [**документации**](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)  написанно

> React.memo — это компонент высшего порядка. Он похож на
> React.PureComponent, но предназначен для функциональных компонентов.

То есть точно также как работает `PureComponent`.Если один из пропсов либо состояние компонента не изменяется то компонент не рендерится.В вашем случае проблема в пропсах.

У вас даже `useEffect` есть который слушает изменения определенного пропса.

```
useEffect(() => {
    get_listAllPosts()
}, [get_listAllPosts]);
```

Comment: @Y.Vugar у вас пропсы меняються уберите их и заново смотрите.

Comment: когда убираю useEffect, тогда все по прежнему

Comment: @Y.Vugar так я же написал наверху.

Comment: Я понял вас. Просто хотел знать, что нормально ли в этом случае, что компонент вызывается дважды? Должен ли я оставить это или сделать что-то?

Comment: @Y.Vugar что вы называете нормальным ?Можно конкретнее?`Memo` компонент может рендерится десять раз это тоже будет нормальным все зависет от ситуации.